# Apache 2.4 virtual host on different port than 80

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

When reading the articles it all seems easy, but I am unable to get this to work. I run apache 2.4.7 
Several virtual hosts are running just fine. I need one virtual host to run at port 8080 only. So I added Listen 8080 to ports.conf

In the virtualhost conf file:

> VirtualHost *:8080>

After a restart I am not getting the virtual host. I do see the default server page and I also notice that the Listen 8080 line is working.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: Did you enable your site using `a2ensite <site>`?

Comment: Off topic on this site.   Try ServerFault.

Comment: Yes I did, I will move this to ServerFault